# To express that I ordered food for take-out, do I use 「持ち帰り食べ物」 or just 「持ち帰り」?

Tags: grammar, usage, nuances

The sentence I formed is 「持ち帰り食べ物用を買うしました。」
My intended meaning is, "I ordered food for take-out". 
I'm not sure whether the construction is grammatically correct or if it's redundant.

I'd like to share my process for forming this sentence, since I like to try making sentences out of new words I learn in my self-study:

I recently read that 「持【も】ち帰【かえ】り」is used to mean "takeout/to-go" in the context of ordering food, much like the loanword 「テイクアウト」. As such, I wanted to practise constructing a sentence using that word.

Since "to buy" is 「買【か】う」, I decided to use that because I wasn't sure what the appropriate word for "order" (in this context) was. I read that 「注文【ちゅうもん】」 can refer to an order, but I'm not sure if this can only be used as a noun.

As "food" is 「食【た】べ物【もの】」, I thought of specifying that the take-out order is food, and nothing else. I am not certain if saying 「持【も】ち帰【かえ】り食【た】べ物【もの】」 is redundant or not (and if it isn't, I wasn't sure if I should express it as 「食【た】べ物【もの】の持【も】ち帰【かえ】り」 or just say 「持ち帰り食べ物」. )

I'd usually refer to Japanese language sites or a cursory Google search to determine if my sentence construction is natural enough to appear on Japanese-language posts, but everything I could find about 「持【も】ち帰【かえ】り」 seems to cater to people *ordering food from an establishment*, rather than *talking about having ordered food from an establishment*.

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: I'm not native, but judging from the usages of 持ち帰り that I have heard, 持ち帰りを買いました is what I'd say.

Comment: @Sweeper, I'm not native either, but that  seems reasonable. 

333 , I think including  食べ物 **would** be redundant. Not only unnecessary, but odd.

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you (to ericfromabeno as well, since I cannot notify you in this comment!) I find it interesting that the form used here was 「買い」instead of 「買う」. Just to clarify, is the conjugation/logic behind that 「買う + いました」?

Comment: 普通は「お持ち帰り*のギョーザ*を注文しました」「お持ち帰り*のラーメン*を買いました」「テイクアウト*のピザ*を買いました」「牛丼*のテイクアウトをし*ました」「ハンバーガー*を*テイクアウトしました」「カレー*をお持ち帰りし*ました」とかいう感じだと思います・・・（食べ物の名称を入れて・・）

Comment: @Chocolate なるほどですね… ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the thought process behind your translation attempt. ^_^

First, 「持ち帰り」literally means "to take, and then leave". In almost every conceivable shopping situation, this is exactly what you do, once you've bought something. You leave the store. Only with the purchase of food in a restaurant that has tables for their customers would you ever need to differentiate between a purchase to be bagged so you can leave with it, vs. a purchase placed on a tray so you can enjoy it while still in the shop, which is 店内 (tennai)... So deliberately including the word "food" in your translation is as you suspected, redundant.

Japan is a language full of convenient short-form sentences, and this word is one such example. If you go into a McDonald's, you can simply say your order, then 持ち帰りで、お願いします。　which is "As take-out, please." or "I'd like that to go, please."  Similarly, if you want to eat in, you can say 店内で、お願いします。

If you are telling someone a story about having bought food as take-out, the simplest way is to say Xを持ち帰りにした。"I bought X as take-out."

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response! I'm familiar with how to order food in a restaurant as a direct 「持【も】ち帰【かえ】りで、お願【ねがい】いします」, but was at a loss as to how I can tell someone else that I bought food as take-out.

Explaining the meaning of 「持ち帰り」is especially helpful! I caught 「帰り」, but not 「持ち」. Thank you, too, for introducing me to 「店内」! I will try to form sentences with that new vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

When ordering takeout usually you say お持ち帰り**で**お願いします。So If you wanted to say "I ordered takeout ramen" you could say:

> 僕はラーメンをお持ち帰り**で**買ってきた。

Or if you wanted to say "order" then you could use 注文 in a similar fashion. If you wanted to say "I ordered takeout" you could say:

> 僕はお持ち帰りで注文しました。

I don't believe there's a way to make takeout a noun by adding 物 or 食べ物.

Comment: Just to clarify, since I recall 「で」as a 助詞【じょし】that approximates "by", do your sentences literally mean "I ordered ramen **by** takeout" and "I took-out **by** order", respectively?

Comment: ^ で has several meanings.. here it's like "in the form of".

Comment: @Chocolateさんもありがとうございます！